# Retrieving data from one table while comparing value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

**Overview**

I have two tables as can be seen below:

```
user_planes
----------------------------------
|id |user_id|plane_id|fuel|status|
----------------------------------
| 2     1        1     1   Ready |
----------------------------------

shop_planes
------------------------
|id |name|fuel_capacity|
------------------------
| 1   bob       3      |
------------------------

Foreign Key              Primary Key
user_planes.plane_id <-> shop_planes.id
```

I want to be able to get every field (`SELECT *`) in `user_planes` and `name` and `fuel_capacity` based on the following criteria:

- `WHERE user_planes.user_id = ?` - Parameter which will be added to the query through PHP.
- `WHERE user_planes.status = 'Ready'`
- `WHERE user_planes.fuel < shop_planes.fuel_capacity`

**The Issue and My Attempts**

I've tried `JOIN` however it retrieves data which doesn't fit that criteria, meaning it gets extra data which is from `shop_planes` and not `user_planes`.

```
SELECT * FROM `user_planes` WHERE fuel IN (SELECT shop_planes.fuel_capacity FROM shop_planes WHERE fuel < shop_planes.fuel_capacity) AND user_planes.user_id = 1 AND status = 'Ready'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `user_planes` INNER JOIN `shop_planes` ON user_planes.fuel < shop_planes.fuel_capacity AND user_planes.user_id = 1 AND user_planes.status = 'Ready'
```

- I've searched Stackoverflow and looked through many questions but I've not been able to figure it.
- I've looked up many tutorials but still can't get the desired result.

The desired result is that the query should use the data stored in `user_planes` to retrieve data from `shop_planes` while at the same time not getting any excess data from `shop_planes`.

**Disclaimer**

I really struggle using `JOIN` queries, I could use multiple separate queries however I wish to optimise my queries hence I'm trying to bring it in to one query.

If their isn't clarity in the question, please do say, I'll update it to the best of my ability.

**Note** - Is there an easy query builder option available either through phpmyadmin or an alternative software?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you need to learn use `JOIN` just follow a basic [**tutorial**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/DEfaULT.asP). There isnt a query builder

Comment: Sorry I just fix it

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've tried the W3Schools tutorial, and it just went *whoosh* over my head, I then tried some code and still I couldn't grasp it, hence I turned to Stackoverflow.

Comment: as a note the select * is returning your "extra columns" select * is telling the query to return everything, when you join two tables together you are effectively making one giant table containing all columns from both. If you do want every column from user planes you can use userplanes.* or best practice is to declare the columns you want individually this has the benefit that if you were to say add a new column to user planes any code that selects from it won't have to have to then handle the new column as it wouldn't suddenly start to be returned

Comment: @MarkD understood, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt was not a bad one, the only thing you missed there was the join criteria you described at the beginning of your post. I also moved the other filters to the `where` clause to better distinguish between join condition and the filters.

```
SELECT `user_planes`.*
FROM `user_planes`
INNER JOIN `shop_planes` ON user_planes.plane_id = shop_planes.id 
WHERE user_planes.fuel < shop_planes.fuel_capacity AND user_planes.user_id = 1 AND user_planes.status = 'Ready'
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need the base `JOIN`

```
  SELECT up.*  -- only user_plane fields
  FROM shop_planes sp  -- CREATE alias for table or field
  JOIN user_planes up
    ON sp.id  = up.plane_id
```

Case 1:  apply a filter in where condition with php parameter.

```
  SELECT up.*
  FROM shop_planes sp
  JOIN user_planes up
    ON sp.id  = up.plane_id 
  WHERE up.user_id = ?
```

Case 2:  apply a filter in where condition with string constant

```
  SELECT up.*
  FROM shop_planes sp
  JOIN user_planes up
    ON sp.id  = up.plane_id 
  WHERE user_planes.status = 'Ready'
```

Case 3: aply filter comparing fields from both tables

```
  SELECT up.*
  FROM shop_planes sp
  JOIN user_planes up
    ON sp.id  = up.plane_id
  WHERE up.fuel < sp.fuel_capacity
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
      up.id AS User_Plane_ID
    , up.[user_id]
    , up.plane_id
    , up.fuel
    , up.[status]
    , sp.name AS shop_Plane_Name
    , sp.fuel_capacity AS shop_Plane_Fuel_Capacity
FROM User_Planes up
INNER JOIN Shop_Planes sp ON up.plane_id = sp.id  
    AND up.fuel < sp.Fuel_Capacity
WHERE up.[status] = 'Ready'
    AND up.[user_id] = ?
```

Definitely find a tutorial for JOINs, and don't use SELECT *. With SELECT *, you may end up querying much more than you actually need and it can cause problems if the table changes. You'll enjoy your day much more if you explicitly name the columns you want in your query.

I've aliased some of the columns (with AS) since some of those column names may be reserved words. I've also moved the JOIN criteria to include a filter on fuel